# How to get the color code from and xml file so that it could be used in the MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, xml

So let's say in my colors.xml file I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name = "cyan100">#B2EBF2</color>
    <color name = "cyan200">#80DEEA</color>
    <color name = "cyan400">#26C6DA</color>
</resources>
```

In my MainActivity.java I have this:

```
    String js = "<html><head>"
            + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='file:///android_asset/mathscribe/jqmath-0.4.0.css'>"
            + "<script src = 'file:///android_asset/mathscribe/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>"
            + "<script src = 'file:///android_asset/mathscribe/jqmath-etc-0.4.2.min.js'></script>"
            + "</head><body bgcolor = "+ **<GET CYAN100 COLOR CODE>** +"><font color = \"white\">"
            + "<script>var s =   '$$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$';M.parseMath(s);document.write(s);</script> </font></body>";
    layout_start.loadDataWithBaseURL("", js, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

How do I get the cyan100 color code for  from the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Call `getResources().getColor(R.id.cyan100)` on your `Activity`. That will return the `int` value of the color, which you will need to convert into a string in `#RRGGBB` format for splicing into your HTML.

Comment: How to convert to string?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the color code in such a way

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan100)));
```